# Flatten (reassign values of) hotspots in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix in the following format:

```
set.seed(1)
m = matrix(sample(c(0,0,0,1),25,rep=T), nrow=5)
m[13] = 4
print(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    4    1    0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0
```

Consider `[3,3]` is some hotspot that we want to 'flatten' by spreading it's value across the nearest neighbouring/nearby cells of zero value.   In this case that means assigning 1 to cells `[2,3]`, `[3,2]` and `[4,3]` so that `[3,3]` can also be reduced to 1:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0
```

Is anyone aware of a matrix/raster operation that can achieve this efficiently, while preserving the sum total of all the cells?

Comment: What if there was a 3 or 5 instead of 4?

Comment: I have no preference about prioritisation of equally-distant zero-value cells - if that's what you're asking? - just that closer cells are prioritised..

Comment: Any suggestion @docendo-discimus now I've (hopefully) addressed your query?

Comment: Yes you answered my question, but unfortunately I don't have a good suggestion at the moment.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you or one your 4 up-markers might've had something to contribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got interested in this question, so I made an attempt. There, probably, exists a "rastery" tool for what you're trying but I'm not aware.

First, a helper function that finds the indices of elements of a square surrounding a specific element in a matrix:

```
find_neighbors = function(i, j, n)
{
    tmp = expand.grid(replicate(2, -n:n, simplify = F))
    tmp2 = tmp[rowSums(abs(tmp) < n) < 2, ]
    inds = cbind(tmp2[, 1] + i, tmp2[, 2] + j)
    inds[order(rowSums(abs(cbind(inds[, 1] - i,        ##so that up/down/right/left are filled before diagonal neighbors
                                 inds[, 2] - j)))), ]
}
```

E.g.:

```
m1 = matrix(0, 7, 8)
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
m1[find_neighbors(3, 4, 1)] = 1
m1[find_neighbors(3, 4, 2)] = 2
m1[find_neighbors(3, 4, 3)] = 3
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    3    2    2    2    2    2    3    0
#[2,]    3    2    1    1    1    2    3    0
#[3,]    3    2    1    0    1    2    3    0
#[4,]    3    2    1    1    1    2    3    0
#[5,]    3    2    2    2    2    2    3    0
#[6,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

And the function that flattens the hot-spots. There is a nested loop. The first "for" to loop over the hotspots and the second to iteratively flatten the hotspot to its neighbors. Nevertheless, the loop is exitted once the spot is flattened.

```
ff = function(mat, thres = 1)
{    
    wh = which(mat > thres, T)

    for(r in seq_len(nrow(wh))) {   
        for(n in seq_len(max(c(dim(mat) - wh[r, ], wh[r, ] - 1)))) {
            if(mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] <= thres) break  #stop flattening if we are done

            inds = find_neighbors(wh[r, 1], wh[r, 2], n) #get indices of neighbours
            inds = inds[!((rowSums(inds <= 0) > 0) | #use valid indices..
                        inds[, 1] > nrow(mat) |   
                        inds[, 2] > ncol(mat)), ]

            inds = inds[mat[inds] < thres, , drop = F] #use indices that are allowed to take values         
            tofill = nrow(inds) * thres #how many 'units' need to be taken from the hotspot?

            mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] = mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] + sum(mat[inds])  #in case the neighbors 
                                                                          #of the hotspot are > 0,
                                                                          #the, just, increase the 
                                                                          #value of the hotspot                                                     
            if(mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] <= tofill) tofill = mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] - thres #do we have enough 
                                                                                 #'units' in the hotspot?

            if(tofill > 0) {
                if(tofill < thres) {
                    mat[inds[1, , drop = F]] = tofill
                    mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] = mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] - tofill                    
                    next
                }
                nr = tofill %/% thres
                mat[inds[seq_len(nr), , drop = F]] = thres
                if((tofill %% thres) > 0) mat[inds[nr + 1, , drop = F]] = tofill %% thres
                mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] = mat[wh[r, , drop = F]] - tofill
            }           
        }
    }

    mat
}
```

And an example:

```
mm = matrix(0, 11, 9); mm[8, 2] = 12; mm[6, 7] = 4
mm
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    4    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [8,]    0   12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ff(mm)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
# [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# [7,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ff(mm, 3)
ff(mm, 5)
ff(mm, 1500)
```

Hope any of these will be helpful.

Comment: This is pretty neat work. It needs a little refining I think as it misbehaves when a hotspot-flatten operation encounter another in its neighbourhood: e.g. `mm = matrix(0, 8, 6); mm[5, 4] = 7; mm[4, 3] = 2;
mm;
ff(mm)`.  (Notice the `[4,3]` hole that has appeared?) I'm looking into that.  Otherwise this looks much slimmer than the code I've achieved so far, so thanks Alexis.

Comment: Alexis - I've been working through your code for a couple of hours and am struggling to get my head around it.  Specifically the role of `tofill` is unclear.  Also, I realise the need for a second loop, but not sure about the rationale for formulation `seq_len(max(dim(mat) - c(wh)))`.

Comment: @geotheory : I editted part of "ff" to address your first comment and to, also, cover the cases where the neighbors are "< thres" but "> 0" too, that I had ignored at first.

Comment: @geotheory : As to your second comment. I think of "tofill" as "If all neighbors were to be filled, so that the threshold is reached, how big should the hotspot be? Is the hotspot big enough to fill all neighbors?". If we had the convenience to, just, loop over the neighbors and -iteratively- flatten the hotspot without efficiency loss, the step to build "tofill" would be much simpler, I believe.

Comment: @geotheory : The `seq_len(max(c(dim(mat) - wh[r, ], wh[r, ] - 1)))` (had some mistakes here too) is to find the maximum number of the search for surrounding neighbors so that we don't loop, unnessecarily, in negative row/column indices. This step finds the distance of the hotspot from both rows and columns and choose the maximum; i.e. where the looping is useless furthermore.

Answer (score 1):

Possible outline of an attack.

1) find the hotspots:

```
hotind <- which (m > 1, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

2) loop over the rows of hotind to spread:

```
for (j in 1: nrow(hotind) {
    hotpoint <- hotind[j,]
   # for example, divvy up the hot value into four nearest neighbors
    m[hotpoint[1]-1,hotpoint[2]-1] <- m[hotpoint[1],hotpoint[2]]/4
   # do_same_for m[hotpoint[1]+1,hotpoint[2]-1] and_so_on
   m[hotpoint[1],hotpoint[2]] <- 1 # or your choice of final value
}
```

It sure "feels" to me like there's a way to do this with a smoothing convolution kernel approach, so here's hoping someone posts a slicker method.